# How to fetch a string using PDO

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I have a `postgred` db, and I want to fetch a specific string value from a table, and then do a condition to see if that string was found. This is my code:

```
function tipo_utilizador($username, $password) {

    global $conn;
    $user = $conn->prepare("SELECT type
                            FROM utilizador2 
                            WHERE name = :username  AND password = :password"); 
    $user->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $user->bindParam(':password', $password);
    $user->execute();

    return $user->fetch();

}
```

And then I do an if condition like:

```
$some_variable = 0;
$var = tipo_utilizador($username, $password);

if($var == "admin") {
    $some_variable=1;
}

echo $some_variable;
```

But when I echo `$some_variable`, it always returns 0. The `SQL` code works fine, and the username and password echos are okay too.
The error seems to be inside the function, but I don't know what it is. Can someone help me?

Comment: Do `print_r($var);` and you will see it

Comment: `->fetch()` returns an array, not a column. You might also want to just query by username and switch to password_hash/verify instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
$var=tipo_utilizador($username, $password);

if($var=="admin")
```

Your function returns an array, so you will need to get the correct element from that array:

```
if ($var['type'] === "admin")
```

Answer (score 1):

The fetch method will return an array with the fields as keys, not a single string.  You would need something like this

```
 $var=tipo_utilizador($username, $password);

 if($var['type'] == "admin") {
   $some_variable = 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do:

```
print_r($var);
```

You will see why it is not working! Because it's an array, so use this:

```
if ($var['type'] == "admin")
```